# GAE/Java LocalChannelFailureException at development server

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I'm using [Channel API (Java)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) with Google App Engine for my web application. I have implemented a Token-reusing-mechanism for not exceeding the [Channel API Quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=de#Channel) that fast.
This means, that my implementation reuses an existing channel for a user that refreshes the page as long as the expiration time of the token received by the `ChannelService.createChannel()` call, is not over.

When refreshing my page I get the following exception (with `x` starting at 0 and increasing for every refresh). However, my page continues to work as intended. Is there a way to avoid the exception being thrown? Or can I just ignore the exception?

```
com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.LocalChannelFailureException: Client connection with ID connection-x not found.
at com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.Channel.getClientMessageQueue(Channel.java:79)
at com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.ChannelManager.getNextClientMessage(ChannelManager.java:300)
at com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.LocalChannelServlet.doGet(LocalChannelServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
...
```

Im reusing tokens with the following classes:

When calling `ChannelService.createChannel()` I save the expiration date and the generated token in an Entity called "Channel"

```java
public class Channel {
    private String id;
    private String token;
    private Date expiration;
}
```

Then I have a ChannelService class that returns a valid Channel with its `get()` method. The channelDAO is a class that just uses a Map for storing Channels. So there is no database persistence, which would keep a token alive over a server restart.

```java
public Channel get(String clientId) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Channel channel = channelDAO.get(clientId);
    if (channel == null || calendar.getTime().after(channel.getExpiration())) {
        com.google.appengine.api.channel.ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory
                .getChannelService();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, CHANNEL_UPTIME);
        String token = channelService.createChannel(player.toString(), CHANNEL_UPTIME);
        channel = new Channel(clientId, token, calendar.getTime());
        channelDAO.persist(channel);
    }
    return channel;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem by further investigations on the source of the exception. The Channel API works with polling requests that are executed every 500ms. I used Firefox's console to track these. Here is an example poll:

```
[20:40:15.978] GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/channel/dev?command=poll&channel=920a60f9b27ece1a1ba43d251fdacf2e-channel-eqt3xi-1385927324758-{clientId}&client=connection-2 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```

In my question I stated, that the exception occurs on page reload, so the problem with this was: When the page is reloaded, something (I don't know what exactly, but i assume it has something to do with sockets getting closed and reopened on page refresh) happens which causes the **client** (last parameter of the GET request) to no longer be available. However, a new client is available: the client "connection-{i+1}". So when you enter the page initially, the client is "connection-0". After page refresh it is "connection-1". But as the old page used a delayed execution for the poll, a false request (still connection-0) is sent to the server, that, as a result, throws the Exception.

I fixed the problem by manually cancelling the delayed execution, when leaving the page with jQuery.

```js
var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('${channel.token}');
var socket = channel.open(handler);
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    clearTimeout(socket.pollingTimer_);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your token re-use scheme should be carefully checked for bugs as that exception shouldn't occur each page reload.

There is a [known issue after local server restarts](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9539) but as stated it should only be only if the development server restarted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some details about my reusing mechanism. Would you look over it and tell me what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using GWT and gwt-gae-channel. The solution would be something like:

```
Socket socket = channel.open(new SocketListener() {...});
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
                    socket.close();
            }
    });
```